# Replace path string including environment variable

Tags: unix, awk, log4j, substring

I'm trying to get application log path from log4j.properties and trying to make it a dynamic path. 
The log file in log4j.properties includes {catalina.base} and I want to replace it with $CATALINA_HOME enviroment variable.
I used the string replacement in below.

**Here is the code;**

/* Get the log path from log4j.properties */

> logfile=$(awk '/LOGFILE.File/{print $NF}' $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/"$filename"/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties | grep -Po 'LOGFILE.File=\K[^"]*')

/* Replace {catalina.base} with $CATALINA_HOME */

> convertlogfile="${logfile/"{catalina.base}"/$CATALINA_HOME}"

/* see the output */

> echo $convertlogfile

The problem is the output is:
$/usr/local/tomcat/logs/Application.log

I couldn't get rid of the initial '$' sign and I couldn't use the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the output of `echo $convertlogfile` is `$/usr/local/tomcat/logs/Application.log`,
then the value of `$logfile` must be `${catalina.base}`.
And then I don't understand why you want to use a pattern replacement when you could do simply:

```
convertlogfile=$CATALINA_HOME
```

But anyway, to strip the `$` at the beginning, you could write the replacement like this, but then again, I don't see the point:

```
convertlogfile="${logfile/"\${catalina.base}"/$CATALINA_HOME}"
```